# Java library to organize restricted access sections

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm often need to organize something like critical section where multiple thread might access simultaneously but not more than X threads with the same key.

Simplified example:

- thread pool to process the device commands from queue;
- queue contains commands for different devices;
- while one thread process device command other threads that process commands for the same device should wait their turn.

I know this could be achieved in different ways and you could say that there are  architectural refactoring required and so on but this is the simplest example I could think.

Edit: I don't need the solution for this particular example, I need some library which allows to restrict access based on some key for example device IP/MAC string. For example: getLock().lock(deviceIP)

I have my own code to do this but I wounder did I miss something? Is there some standard Java SE 8 components or third-party libraries to do this?

Comment: `synchronized (device)` ? `device.getLock().lock()`?

Comment: I don't need the solution for example, I need some library which allows to restrict access based on some key for example device IP/MAC. For example:
getLock().lock(IP);

Comment: Asking for a library is off-topic here. And anyway, my guess is that all you need is in the JDK. If you have a concrete problem, post it, with the code you tried, and explain clearly what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry for off topic and thanks for your time.